# Selenium JAVA get parameter from a URL

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver

I have the following URL that I need to get the 4805206 code from.

```
 href="http://adserver.adtech.de/adlink|832|4805206|0|1686|AdId=9624985;BnId=1;itime=527032581;nodecode=yes;link=http://URL/Recruiters/Lex-Consultancy-3979.aspx"
```

I was wondering if its possible to do this and if so how?

Heres my Java Selenium Class

```
    public void checkAdTechKeys(WebDriver driver) {

    if(driver.getCurrentUrl().equalsIgnoreCase("URL"))
    {
        HP_LeftSearchBox(driver);//enter search terms
        driver.get("URL");
        // driver.findElement(By.linkText("Read     More")).getAttribute("href").toString();
                    String url = new String(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Read More")).getAttribute("href").toString());
                //  url = url.split("|")[2];
                 System.out.println(url);
    }else{
        setup.loadHomePage(driver);
        checkAdTechKeys(driver);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code with a small modification that prints out that number:

```
driver.get("http://irishjobs.ie/");
String url = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Read More")).getAttribute("href");
String[] parsedUrl = url.split("\\|");
System.out.println(parsedUrl[2]);
```

Two things that you missed:

- escaping the "|"
- .split() returns an array of strings, not a string.